# Strange behavior from Excel.Worksheet.Cells[row, column]

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, vsto, excel-2010

I have the following method:

```
    public static object getValue(Excel.Worksheet sheet, int row, int col)
    {
        Excel.Range r = sheet.Cells[row, col] as Excel.Range;
        //I've also tried using sheet.get_Range(cell, cell); here, with the same result

        if (r.Row != row || r.Column != col) 
        {   
            //Why does this debug statement sometimes print?
            Debug.Print("Tried to read (" + row.ToString() + ", " + col.ToString() + ") but got (" + r.Row.ToString() + ", " + r.Column.ToString() + ")");
        }

        return r.Value2;
    }
```

Based on my understanding of Excel.Worksheet.Cells[row, column], my code should never enter the if statement. However, when I call getValue repeatedly to read multiple cells, every so often the row and column of the range it returns are different than the row and column I called Excel.Worksheet.Cells with.

Example output: "Tried to read (19, 1) but got (56, 5)"

Furthermore, if I break in the if statement, then rewind my execution point and run Excel.Worksheet.Cells again, I get the correct range.

Why could this be?

Comment: `//Why does this debug statement sometimes print?` Ummm, I am unable to reproduce the above behavior.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I'm not sure what to tell you. It only happens rarely for me. I don't think it's sheet specific, as I've been able to reproduce it on multiple excel sheets. This is an excel ribbon add-in, built in visual studio 2008 with .net 3.5

Comment: A wild shot in the dark. Put this `Excel.Range r = null;` before the line `Excel.Range r...` and change that line to `r = sheet.Cells....`

Comment: @SiddharthRout: `Excel.Range r = null; r = sheet.get_Range(cell, cell);` produces the same behaviour, sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an answer to your direct question, but may solve the problem.

Is `getValue` in a tight loop?  If so then I would approach it a different way.  Since Accessing `Cells` and `Value2` are COM-calls they are slower than normal array accessors.  If you have a particular range you're looping over I would get the *array* of values for that range in memory and access the *array* directly rather than looping through the *cells*.

e.g. instead of

```
for(int r = 1; r <= 10; r++)
    for(int c = 1; c <= 20; c++)    
        double val = sheet.Cells[r,c];
```

do

```
object[,] values = sheet.Range("A1:J20").Value
for(int r = 1; r <= 10; r++)
    for(int c = 1; c <= 20; c++)    
        double val = values[r,c];
```

This *may* fix your problem by removing the COM access from tight loop and eliminating whatever problem is giving you the strange results.

Comment: I think your suggestion is probably a better way of doing things, but unfortunately getValue isn't in a tight loop. I can probably refactor to use your solution, but I thought I'd see if anyone knew why the current method wasn't working first.

Comment: I'm marking your solution as correct, as I suspect it will probably be what most people are looking for. Unfortunately, although `object[,] values = sheet.Range("A1:J20").Value` is really slick, [I also need the interiour colour of the cells](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15888629/1286571). It looks like the only way I can get them is to loop through the sheet.