# Excel: Dump cell attributes to array

Tags: c#, excel, .net-3.5, vsto

I know I can quickly dump the values of excel cells into an array like so:

```
object[,] values = workSheet.UsedRange.Value2 as object[,];
```

Can I do something similar for attributes of cells other than their values? For example, I'd like to get the cell colour, but `object[,] cc = workSheet.UsedRange.Interior.Color as object[,];` results in `cc` being null.

Looping through the sheet to get cell attributes takes orders of magnitude longer.

Comment: There's no built-in support for this.

Comment: In a word....no.  Its easy if you want to set them all to the same thing...but that doesn't seem to be what you are looking for.

Comment: OleDb is a quick way to grab all the values from a large range of cells. It won't do formatting though (i.e. cell colour), just data. Looks like you'll need a third party app to do what you need.

Comment: So i guess the answer is no. Nuts.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never. Briefly, in absence of a code stub,

Save the sheet as an xml formatted file. Read the file in with an xml reader, query the xml object for styleID (or anything else you want or need). Query the styleID's for color attrbiute, and match up same to each cell. LINQ queries on xml database should need only a couple of lines to do all this.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Jeltz, but is that going to be any faster than just looping through the sheet?